# Loop Cut and Slide is altering other Edge Loops

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

My question is about Applying Loop Cut and Slide and that it is now moving the other Edge Loops to space them out but I want to preserve them as I do normally.  I know I have altered something here but I cannot figure out what obvious thing I am missing and why the other existing edge loops slide along away from the new edge loop.  Normally I can place new edge loops to define an edge or create more without modifying the existing shape.

Comment: maybe you've enabled the Proportional Editing option?

Comment: Hmm its off/unselected, its something not on the Tools Settings Toolbar I think.

Comment: could you please show a screenshot/animated gif of what's happening?

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/7nXOvj8GUne7WtswBp/giphy.gif

Answer (score 1):

Disable the *On Cage* option of your *Subdivision Surface* modifier, for the moment you see the edges as they would be if you applied the modifier, and if you move an edge it will move another one:

[image]

Comment: Oh of course!  Im an idiot.  It is that.  Youre a genius, thankyou :)